# What is a channel tap?

Tags: wireless, radio, terminology, physics

In wireless communication, I am confused about what people are referring to when they use the term 'channel tap.'  Can someone explain the term or provide me a definition? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you got a link to anywhere on the web that mentions it?

Comment: Yes, for example what does 'N taps' mean here: http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~jain/cse574-08/ftp/channel_model_tutorial.pdf (pg 7 sec. A.1.5 Tapped Delay Line Model)

Comment: I don't see any occurrence of "channel tap" in that document. There are "taps" for sure...why are you adding "channel"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I added that descriptor bc I know the tap are of the channel. The expression in that pdf is 'N taps' I mentioned

Comment: @PhilFrost the cord channel tap exists n the literature, although I'm also not sure what this really means, not having a background in EE. To see "channel tap", look at P.47 (sec 2.4.1) of theis well known book - http://ee.sharif.edu/~wireless.comm.net/references/Tse,%20Fundamentals%20of%20Wireless%20Communication.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to simulate the effects of multipath fading, a model can be created that consists of a delay line with several taps. A tap in this context is just a point on the delay line corresponding to a certain delay. The signals from each tap can then be "summed" and the composite signal then represents what a real radio wave might look like as received by a receiver and when subject to multipath fading.

The summing I refer to above is just the mixing of the individual signals from the various taps but, importantly, these can be summed together in different ways to simulate how time can play a part in the real mixing of the multipath signals.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That helps a lot.  So, just to make sure I understand, the longer delay taps correspond to longer paths taken by the signal?

Answer (score 0):

One way to represent the impulse response of a multipath channel is by a discrete number of impulses.
[image]
Note that the impulse response h varies with time t. The coefficients ci(t) vary with time. There are N coefficients in the above model. The selection of the N and delay values τi depends upon what is considered a significant level. This model represents the channel by a delay line with N taps. For example, the channel can be represented by a 4-tap model as shown in Figure below.

[image]

Comment: This is just copying a section (A.1.5 Tapped Delay Line Model) out of the document the OP already linked to!  (See the second comment under the question.)  You have added nothing.

Comment: @tcrosley-okeys I didn't went to that document and thought this would be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

In the provided link, the 'N taps' only means how many significant paths the wireless signals could go through for wireless communication, it is easy to understand. However, the term 'channel tap' is also used to indicate the channel filter taps in a discrete-time baseband model. It has a comprehensive description and discussion in 2.2.3 of Tse's book ee.sharif.edu/~wireless.comm.net/references.